# Problems with Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

I am experiencing several errors with my Ubuntu installation on Windows 10. I'm just getting into the "Ubuntu World" and could really use some help.

After doing an apt update, I am receiving the following error.

```
  "6 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/var/cache/apt-build/repository/dists/apt-build/InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)"
After doing the apt upgrade I am receiving this message.
  "Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/ca/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/ca/index.db: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/ca/856: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/share/man/ca: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/fr.ISO8859-1/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/fr.ISO8859-1/index.db: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/fr.ISO8859-1/856: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/fr.UTF-8/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/fr.UTF-8/index.db: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/fr.UTF-8/856: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/gl/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/gl/index.db: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/gl/856: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/share/man/gl: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/sk/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/sk/index.db: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/sk/856: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/share/man/sk: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/uk/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/uk/index.db: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/uk/856: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/share/man/uk: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/vi/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/vi/index.db: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/vi/856: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/share/man/vi: Permission denied
Setting up emacs25 (25.2+1-6) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/emacs25 doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package emacs25 (--configure):
 installed emacs25 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs25
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"
```

Please, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is the output of the suggested remedies. And the output of groups.

````
[sudo] password for mark:
Setting up emacs25 (25.2+1-6) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/emacs25 doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package emacs25 (--configure):
 installed emacs25 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs25
mark@Surface-Pro-4:~$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up emacs25 (25.2+1-6) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/emacs25 doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package emacs25 (--configure):
 installed emacs25 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs25
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
mark@Surface-Pro-4:~$ groups
mark adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev lxd netdev```
````

Comment: Did you prefix apt with "sudo"? It is similar to "run as administrator" on Windows.
If not - permission denied on system resources is expected.

Comment: @MarkCribbs the flagging occurred by error. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt install -f`. Also paste the output of `groups` as well.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here is the results/output of the suggested remedies .

Comment: Sorry, it said it was too long so I added it to the original post.

Comment: try running `sudo apt remove emacs25`

Comment: I have and even tried purge instead of remove, but I still get an error. Something to do with the prerm script. If you need the exact error I will be glad to run it and post it.